# i cant get site content usin perl script

Tags: javascript, perl, cookies

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use IO::Select;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTTP::Response;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
use URI::URL;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTTP::Headers;

my $url = "http://www.zone-h.org/archive";

my $cookie_jar= HTTP::Cookies->new;
$cookie_jar->clear;
$cookie_jar->set_cookie(ZH=11e5b6849ca38da2d65328b70e83b4c5);
$cookie_jar->set_cookie(PHPSESSID=3ekj4g38r2mtls63krlkrhevc1);


my $ua= LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->agent('NeonFlash');
$ua->timeout(30);
$ua->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);

my $req= HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $res= ($ua->request($req))->content;



print "$res";
```

This code to get zone-h.org content, but when I run it I get this javascript page: http://www.zone-h.org/js/zh.js

so what is the problem?

```
<html><body>-<script type="text/javascript" src="/z.js" ></script>
<script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("86b33d8444a58c32376785a3ad250859"),b=toNumbers("7e8afef3877883ecd58a95444a210c13"),c=toNumbers("e1afd8ce7ba1c3d18178f4d4624b6db8");document.cookie="ZH="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://www.zone-h.org/archive?zh=1";</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Please use correct interpunction and upcase letters where there are needed.

Comment: I'm not even sure if your code even will compile in the state it is currently in, but: please always `use strict;` when writing Perl scripts.

Comment: Your program doesn't even compile!!! Also, *always* use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`.

Answer (score 4):

The web site you're trying to access has implemented protections against bots -- the script you're looking at is a part of that. Contact the site operator if you need programmatic access to their content.